# Tableau Date function and Y0Y comparsion

Tags: date, tableau-api

I have Column that is in String format such as 2018-03 and I want to convert this to Date format in tableau. Once I have convert these 4 years data I want to compare 2019 data with 2018 and 2021 data with 2020s

Answer (score 0):

To convert to a date use the DATE function:

DATE(LEFT([DateField],5)+RIGHT([DateField],2)+"01")

Check here to see 2 different ways to do [YoY](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-year-on-year-calculation/) - do whichever works better for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `03` in your date `2018-03` corresponds to month, you can convert the string column to date column with the following calculation, where `my_date` is your string column

```
DATE(DATEPARSE("yyyy-MM", [my_date]))
```

See the results

[image]

Note, if however, `03` is quarter, use this calculation instead

```
DATE(DATEPARSE("yyyy-qq", [my_date]))
```

Comment: The DATEPARSE function doesn't work in mine

Comment: Which version of tableau do you use?